# Null error when trying to draw line in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a recursive program that draws a Kosh Snowflake but but gives me an error when I try to run it. Apparently n is null even though I initialize it:

```
Line2D n = new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1);
        g2.draw(n);
```

And here is the full program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
    class turtle{
    double direction,x,y;
    public turtle(double direction, double x, double y)
    {
        this.direction=0;
        this.x=0;
        this.y=0;
    }
    public void move(double length)
    {
        this.x=x+Math.sin(direction)*length;
        this.y=y+Math.cos(direction)*length;
    }
    public void rotate(double angle)
    {
        this.direction=angle;
    }
}
public class fractal extends JComponent
{
    turtle t = new turtle(0,0,0);
    Graphics2D g2;
    public static void main(String [] args)
{
    fractal p = new fractal();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    p.fractal(300,3);
    panel.add(p);
    panel.setSize(900,900);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}
public void fractal(double length,double depth)
{
    if(depth==0)
    {
        double x0=t.x;
        double y0=t.y;
        t.move(length/4);
        double x1=t.x;
        double y1=t.y;
        Line2D n = new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1);
        g2.draw(n);
        x0=t.x;
        y0=t.y;
        t.rotate(60);
        t.move(length/4);
        x1=t.x;
        y1=t.y;
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
        x0=t.x;
        y0=t.y;
        t.rotate(-60);
        t.move(length/4);
        x1=t.x;
        y1=t.y;
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
        x0=t.x;
        y0=t.y;
        t.rotate(0);
        t.move(length/4);
        x1=t.x;
        y1=t.y;
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
    }
    else
    {
        fractal(length/4,depth-1);
        g2.rotate(60);
        fractal(length/4,depth-1);
        g2.rotate(-60);
        fractal(length/4,depth-1);
        g2.rotate(0);
        fractal(length/4,depth-1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: your graphics2D object is null, and that's why it's not working. You need to go through the swing tutorials and learn how to do custom painting: http://www.mathcs.duq.edu/simon/Java6/uiswing/14painting/index.html

Comment: @ControlAltDel Java 6?

Comment: Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting in Swing/AWT works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Graphics2D g2` is `null`. 
Please have a look at some documentation about drawing JComponents, e.g. " [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)".

Comment: Thanks for the answer!